# Sql server issue dealing with huge volume of data

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

i have an requirment like this i need  to delete all the  customer who have not done transaaction for the past 800 days

i have an table **customer where customerID is the primary key**
**creditcard table have columns  customerID,CreditcardID, where creditcard is an primary key**
**Transcation  table  having column transactiondatetime, CreditcardID,CreditcardTransactionID here is the primarary key  in this  table.**

All the transcationtable data is in the  view called  CreditcardTransaction so i am using the  view  to get the  information

i have written an query to get the creditcard  who have  done transaction for the past  800 days and  get their CreditcardID and  store it in table
as the  volume of data in **CreditcardTransaction  view is around 60 millon data** the query what i have writeen fails and logs an message log  file is full and throws message  system out of  memory exception.

```
INSERT INTO Tempcard  
       SELECT CreditcardID,transactiondatetime 
       FROM  CreditcardTransaction WHERE   
       DATEDIFF(DAY ,CreditcardTransaction.transactiondatetime ,getdate())>600
```

As i need  to get the CreditcardID when was their last Transactiondatetime

Need to show  their data in an Excel sheet so, i am dumping in data in an Table then insert them into Excel.

**what is teh best solution i  show  go ahead  here**

**i am using an SSIS package(vs 2008 R2)  where i call an SP dump data into Table  then do  few  business  logic finally insert data in to excel sheet.**

Thanks
prince

Answer (score 1):

One thought: Using a function in a Where clause can slow things down - considerably. Consider adding a column named IdleTransactionDays. This will allow you to use the DateDiff function in a Select clause. Later, you can query the Tempcard table to return the records with IdleTransactionDays greater than 600 - similar to this:

declare @DMinus600 datetime = 
INSERT INTO Tempcard 
(CreditcardID,transactiondatetime,IdleTransactionDays) 
       SELECT CreditcardID,transactiondatetime, DATEDIFF(DAY ,CreditcardTransaction.transactiondatetime ,getdate())
       FROM  CreditcardTransaction

Select * From Tempcard
Where IdleTransactionDays>600

Hope this helps,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're inserting those records row by row. You could create a SSIS package that reads your data with an OLEDB Source component, performs the necessary operations and *bulk inserts* them (a minimally logged operation) into your destination table.

You could also directly output your rows into an Excel file. Writing rows to an intermediate table decreases performance.

If your source query still times out, investigate if any indexes exist and that they are not too fragmented.

You could also partition your source data by year (based on transactiondatetime). This way the data will be loaded in bursts.